# Tomcat6 Java Servlet serving mysql commands?

Tags: java, mysql, apache, tomcat

I've been playing with Java and mysql for awhile. But my first time using it with Tomcat. Are the commands the same, because as far as I can tell its the commands that aren't working.

So far I've got it connecting, and I know this because its maxing out my mysql connections so I have to shut down the Tomcat.

This is my code for the connection and a drop table experiment:

```
public void connect() throws SQLException, NamingException{

    Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
    Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/TestDB");
    con = ds.getConnection();

    dropTables("DROP TABLE test;");

    con.close();
}


public void dropTables(String query) throws SQLException{

    Statement st = (Statement)con.createStatement();        
    st.executeUpdate(query);

}
```

As soon as I uncomment the dropTables, I get HTTP 500.

Any thoughts?

TIA

Here is the error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet myServlet threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.Statement
    at myServlet.dropTables(myServlet.java:90)
    at myServlet.connect(myServlet.java:82)
    at myServlet.doPost(myServlet.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProcessor.process(AjpAprProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpAprProtocol.java:384)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1665)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: HTTP 500 is an internal server error which likely means there was an unhandled exception.  Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Does it show you any exception or otherwise more detailed error information? What do the Tomcat server logs say?

Comment: I'm guessing a NullPointerException or SQLException is bringing down your container.  Check your catalina.out for the evidence.

Comment: Your query is throwing an exception, you should catch it at a higher level and log it. Then post the error here so we can actually help you.

Comment: Post the stacktrace, which may give some clues.

Comment: Posted the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is throwing an exception in the `dropTables` method.  The exception is halting execution, of the `connect` method and preventing you from closing the connection.  This prevents the connection from being returned to the connection pool which causes you to run out of connections.  It is also causing the 500 error.

You can fix your `ClassCastException` by changing `dropTables` to this:

```
public void dropTables(String query) throws SQLException{
    con.createStatement().executeUpdate(query);
}
```

Also, I recommend that you enclose your JDBC code in a try-catch-finally block like so:

```
try{
    dropTables("DROP TABLE test;");
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    con.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement 
cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.Statement
```

You are using a `com.mysql.jdbc.Statement` in your `dropTables(...)` method, but doing so on a `con.createStatement()` which cannot be safely cast for MySQL alone.  Imagine if you (one day) changed your naming look up to return an Oracle database connection.  Perhaps now you can see why the cast is inherently unsafe.

Use a generic `java.sql.Statement`.  Double check your imports and get rid the MySQL imports.  Doing so will make your code far easier to handle when the "next" database you need to support comes down the line.

Comment: What do you mean by a generic java sql statement? My imports look like:

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

Comment: So just have **import java.sql.Statement** and remove **import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement**

Answer (score 1):

When using a connection pool (including DBCP) the JDBC classes will be wrappers around native JDBC driver classes, so you can't cast Connection, PreparedStatement, Statement and ... to driver's specific classes, and why should you do that?

Some implementations have methods for accessing native classes (for example native Oracle connection), but then your code will be dependent to connection pool you use.

Just use standard JDBC interfaces and everything would be fine.